# What is the difference between calling a command via "wsl [command]" and opening a wsl shell and calling "[command]"?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu via WSL 2.0 on Windows 10 and would like to run Texlive from the Windows command line. To do so I prepended the Texlive folder to the path in `/etc/environment` (I also tried a number of other locations eg. `$HOME/.bashrc`):

```
C:\Users\scott\Documents>wsl echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:...

C:\Users\scott\Documents>wsl
scott@SCOTT-PC:/mnt/c/Users/scott/Documents$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:...
```

Why is there a difference between these two paths? Is it possible to change the first PATH variable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To be honest, when I first looked at this question, I thought it would be an easy answer.  Oh how wrong I was.  There are a lot of nuances to how this works.

Let's start with the fairly "easy" part, though.  The main difference between the first method and the second:

- `wsl` by itself launches into a login (and interactive) shell
- the shell launched with `wsl echo $PATH` is neither a login shell nor an interactive shell

So the first will source both login scripts (e.g. `~/.profile`) and interactive startup scripts (e.g. `~/.bashrc`).  The second form does not get to source either of these.

You can see this a different way (and get to the solution) with the following commands:

- `wsl -e bash -c 'echo $PATH'`
- `wsl -e bash -li -c 'echo $PATH'`

The `-li` forces bash to run as a login and interactive shell, thus sourcing all of the applicable startup scripts.  And, as @bovquier points out in the comments, a single quote is needed here to prevent PowerShell from interpolating the `$` before it gets to Bash.  That, or escape it.

You should be able to run TeX Live the same way, just replacing the "echo $PATH" with the startup command you need for TeX Live.

A second option would be to create a script that both adds the path and runs the command, and just launch that script through `wsl /path/to/script.sh`

That said, I honestly don't think that your current login/interactive PATH is coming from `/etc/environment`.  In my testing, at least, `/etc/environment` has no use in WSL, and that's to be expected.  `/etc/environment` is only sourced by PAM modules, and with no login check performed by WSL, there's no reason to invoke PAM in *either* the `wsl` nor the `wsl echo $PATH` commands.

I'd expect that you still have the PATH setting in `~/.bashrc` or somewhere similar), and that's where the shell is picking it up from at the moment.

While this isn't necessarily critical to understanding the answer, you might also wonder, if `/etc/environment` isn't used for setting the default (non-login, non-interactive) path in WSL, what is?  The answer seems to be that it is hard-coded into the `init` that starts up WSL.  That `init` is also what appends the Windows path (assuming you don't have that feature disabled in `/etc/wsl.conf`).