# Running sh script with WSL returns "command not found"

Tags: bash, command-line, sh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have wsl installed, if from the cmd prompt I run:

```
wsl ls
```

it works perfectly, but if if i create a file script.sh and try:

```
wsl script.sh
```

with inside:

```
ls
```

or any other linux command, I get:

```
/bin/bash: script.sh: command not found
```

I have the script in the right folder of course. What causes the issue?

EDIT:
Thanks a lot for the answers. Is i possible to associate .sh files to wsl so that they run automatically with double-click?

Comment: Please see [my instructions in this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1702441/1210833) for how to associate `.sh` with double-click.  It's not exactly straightforward, primarily because you have to translate the Windows path that gets passed in from the CMD interpreter to Linux/WSL equivalents.

Comment: Why don't you accept the answer ? it is very good !

Answer (score 24):

On the surface, this is such a simple question.  I've answered a number of questions on executing commands via the `wsl` command.  This one, however, is subtly complex.  You've added two dimensions to the problem by:

- Attempting to execute the script without a path.
- Not using a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Neither of these is *required*, but they do cause issues if you aren't really aware of what is happening behind the scenes.

First, the "short answer" to your question, then I'll dig in to the explanation and drawbacks of other techniques.

You have a simple script `script.sh` with *just* the following:

```
ls
```

You have the script in the current directory.  To run it via the `wsl` command (from PowerShell, CMD, or other Windows processes), use:

```
wsl -e sh script.sh
```

But don't do that.  Get in the habit of using a shebang line.  Edit the script to be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
ls
```

Set it to be executable for your default user (which it appears that you already have).  Then start it via:

```
wsl -e ./script.sh
```

As far as I know, those are the only two techniques that will run your script efficiently.  Every other method of starting it from the `wsl` command will result in *multiple* shells loading -- Either shells inside of shells, or shells `exec`'ing shells.

###### Why `-e`?  What does it do?

`wsl -e` (or the long-form `wsl --exec`), according to the help:

> Execute[s] the specified command without using the default Linux shell

That allows us to skip the shell entirely or specify a different shell, without incurring the overhead of running the default shell.

So when you run `wsl -e sh script.sh`, that:

- Tells WSL to immediately execute `sh`
- Tells `sh` to read and interpret each line of `script.sh` (see below for a better understanding of "read and interpret")

When you run `wsl -e ./script.sh` on a script with a shebang line, that:

- Tells WSL to immediately execute `./script.sh`
- WSL's `/init` process (which actually runs in all of these cases, but this is the only time we really need to mention it explicitly) sees the first line of the script is a shebang, then loads and runs the script in that shell directly.

###### Why don't other methods of launching work?

To explain why other techniques shouldn't be used is where it truly starts to get complicated.  You have to understand:

- What happens when you ask your shell to *execute* a script file for which you haven't provided a path?
- On the other hand, what happens when you ask your shell to *interpret* a script file for which you haven't provided a path?  Note that it can differ depending on the shell, so we'll stick with `bash` since that's what you are using.
- Which is WSL attempting to do in your case?
- What happens when you ask your shell to execute a script with a shebang line?
- On the other hand, as you are doing, what happens if you ask a shell to execute a script *without* a shebang line?
- The `-e` argument to the `wsl` command -- What happens with it vs. without it?  We've already covered this above, of course.

Wow!  Right?!  All of that?

So with that in mind, let me give some examples of other ways of executing your script, why they don't work, or why they work less efficiently:

---

###### `wsl script.sh` (your original example)

You might think this would be the same as running `bash script.sh` from inside Linux/WSL, but it's not quite.

`bash script.sh` (inside WSL) works, because it is *reading and interpreting* each line in the script as a command to be executed by `bash` itself.  Since it is not *executing* the script, it doesn't require a path.  The shell just reads the file in the current directory.

`wsl script.sh` (outside WSL) doesn't work, because it is actually attempting to *execute* the script using your default user's shell (`bash` in this case).  It's the rough equivalent of calling `bash -c script.sh` from within WSL/Linux.  To execute a file, either file needs to be in a directory in the search path (represented by the `PATH` environment variable) or you need to provide an absolute or relative path to the file (e.g. `bash -c ./script.sh` or `wsl ./script.sh`).

More reading on the difference between executing a script and interpreting it (although it doesn't use that exact terminology) can be found in [this excellent Unix & Linux stack answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179305/432493).

---

###### `wsl sh script.sh` (or `wsl sh ./script.sh`)

Either of these *will* run your script, but they actually load the shell two times.  This:

- Starts your default shell (`bash`)
- Asks `bash` to execute (`-c`) `sh script.sh`
- `bash` turns around and `exec`'s `sh` (replacing the `bash` process with the `sh` process
- Then `sh` *reads and interprets* (rather than *executes*) your script.

Because `sh` is reading and interpreting your script, it can do that from the current directory without requiring a path (or for the file to be in a directory on the `$PATH`).

But it just doesn't make sense to load two different shells.  The original `wsl -e sh script.sh` only runs the `sh` and skips `bash` entirely, saving on load time.

Note:  Whether or not you have a shebang line doesn't matter in this case, because the shebang only comes into play when *executing* the script.  `sh` sees that line as a comment when *reading and interpreting* and just skips it.

---

###### `wsl ./script.sh` (without a shebang line)

Also loads two shells.  Remember, this is like running `bash -c ./script.sh`.  It:

- Loads `bash` (or your default shell, if it is different)
- Tells the shell (Bash) to execute `./script.sh` from the current directory
- Bash sees that there is no shebang in the file, so it determines that it is going to run it in it Bash's "fallback" shell, which is itself.
- So Bash then `exec`'s a new `bash` process, replacing the current one, in which to execute the script.

---

###### `wsl ./script.sh` (with a shebang line)

It's very similar to the "no shebang" case, but instead of dropping back to the "fallback", Bash uses whatever you tell it to on the shebang line (`sh` in this case).

It still `exec`'s an instance of `sh`, replacing the parent, calling `bash` process.

---

###### `wsl -e sh -c ./script.sh`

That's got to work, right?  I mean, we're telling WSL to load `sh` and execute the script -- What else could it do?

Yes, again, it works.  But again, we're loading the shell twice.  Once explicitly (via `-e`) and again once the shell determines *how* to execute the script (via shebang or fallback).

It's easiest to see this by changing the script to be:

```
ps -ef
```

Without a shebang, `wsl -e sh -c ./script.sh` returns:

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2638 pts/1    00:00:00 sh
 2639 pts/1    00:00:00   sh
 2640 pts/1    00:00:00     ps
```

With a shebang, `wsl -e sh -c ./script.sh` returns:

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2643 pts/1    00:00:00 sh
 2644 pts/1    00:00:00   test.sh
 2645 pts/1    00:00:00     ps
```

With our proposed `wsl -e ./script.sh`, we see:

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2651 pts/1    00:00:00 test.sh
 2652 pts/1    00:00:00   ps
```

---

###### But wait, there's more?!

If this isn't enough to give you shell/script/shebang nightmares, then just one quick note that sometimes you *will* want to execute the parent shell, even if it means then turning around and loading a subprocess.

This can be the case if your script needs something from your startup files.  When executing *any* of the previous command lines, WSL starts the shell as a non-login, non-interactive shell.

This means that your `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` aren't processed, which can lead to some confusion if there is a change you made in them (e.g. the `PATH` or some other environment variable) that your script expects.

In that case, call something like:

```
wsl -e bash -lic ./script.sh
```

This will force a "login, interactive" shell and process your startup config.

Note that it's probably also possible to modify your shebang line to force this, but I'm going to skip any instruction on that, since this answer/book/treatise has become quite long enough ;-)

For more reading, though, I'll point you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66048183/11810933) if you need it.

Comment: which shell runs the script this way?: wsl ./script.sh

Comment: @AlbertoB I updated the answer to address that question (and more)

Comment: Good answer; I think the shebang should be #! not !# though

Comment: @WarrenSpencer Thanks - Definite typo on my part!  Keep in mind that you can edit to correct (and gain rep for a while by doing so).  Would you like to?  Feel free to find 6 other characters to change.  I can always revert them.

Comment: Thanks @NotTheDr01ds, please feel free to go ahead and edit it, I'm not too interested in the rep

Answer (score 3):

The general way of launching a script, is not simply `script.sh`, but:

```
sh script.sh
```

So, using `wsl`, you might try:

```
wsl sh script.sh
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: it works thanks, I would add 
"wsl ./script.sh"
so that the source command works too

Comment: I think the OP wants to run it as bash script. Therefore `wsl bash script.sh` would be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question (and the answers) confuse multiple separate issues.  The number of combinations of ways to run a script mean other examples can be subjective, inconsistent and there are a surprising number of edge cases, that I am fairly sure differ between OS/shell version combinations.

This answer tries to demonstrate and clarify some of that.

Here we look at parsing a bash script vs loading and running an executable, and considers how the shell finds that executable in the first place.

....You can skip over most of this and get to the exciting bit later if you like.

---

Consider the original questions, the reasons for this issue are:

1. Linux only looks for executable or scripts on the PATH unless you
   give an explicit command path (expended from the command line)
2. The environment (shell etc) you get depends on how you run bash (or
   sh). The PATH that is formed is depedent on this
3. There are hidden differences between shell behaviour and not all shells
   on all distribtions are configured the same, both at compile time and
   during install/configure

### (1) How Linux finds commands

Even if a file is executable (either a script or a binary) you have to use a full path (after expansion) for the OS to run it.

i.e. `/path/my_command` and `./my_command` work but `my_command` does not.

That is different for a shell, e.g. `bash` requires the name of a file given to it as a parameter is a sourcable script, not an executable (unless you use -c)

e.g. Imagine The folders `/bin` and `~/.local/bin` are the `PATH`

- `bash path/to/my_script` will work
- `./my_script` will also work (if cwd is path/to)
- `my_script` won't work unless my_script lives in `~/.local/bin`

### (2)  How bash invocation works

There are a number of different system and user login scripts, and depending on which of `sh` (really `dash`), `bash` or `bash`-pretending-to-be-`sh`, there are zero or more of these are incorporated in the command environment.

For me (on Ubuntu 22.04) there are four files affecting the environemnt, though not all distros are the same.

- /etc/bash.bashrc
- /etc/profile
- ~/.profile
- ~/.bashrc

And two possible shells

- /bin/sh -> /usr/bin/dash
- /bin/bash

It seems the `sh` 'posix' mode of `bash` is not used in my distro, though there is nothing stopping it being used.

### (3) 'Hidden' differences

- Ubuntu, for instance, does not use the older `sh` by default it actually
  uses `dash`, a later implementation of `sh` that is almost but not exactly
  the same (much pain in the past for me there)
- `bash` can emulate `sh` either explicitly or by inferance, and that depends
  on how the OS instance is configured.
- There are compile time switches that make different distributions of the
  same shell behave differently dpeending on who built it.
- Then there are toolboxes (e.g. busybox) that bundle shell commands and
  change behaviour in the process.
- Shell behaviour can be configured to be sensitive to environment variables
  and whether that environment is adoped or not bu sub-shells is a
  configuration parameter in itself.

---

As I am using Ubuntu I will just consider bash (in bash mode) and the dash implementation of sh.

Which of these are really used depends on what shell from above and how bash is called.  (see the very terse [man bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) if you need more)

We can look at the four modes of shell invocation

- login/interactive
- non-login/interactive
- login/non-interactive
- non-login/non-interactive

What environment (e.g. $PATH) results depends on several things, e.g. what `set` flags are set, how the shell is invoked, that environment of that invocation and what the executable ($0) is called.

Because `sh` is often a symlink or alias to `bash` (or in this case `dash`) it can be that `bash` pretends it is `sh`. It also depends what mode dash/bash/sh is started in. There are also environment variables and other bash switches that change behavour more, just to complicate things, thse are ignored for brevity.

So, ignoring those complications, to answer half of the question, simply try the following yourself (examples are in `powershell`, but `cmd` should also work the same, I think)

### Exciting bit....

---

~/work/wsl_sh/ls-sb.sh (mode 766)

```bash
echo "Running 'ls' in $SHELL($SHLVL)"
ls -1
echo "I am $0"
```

~/work/wsl_sh/ls+sb.sh (mode 766)

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./ls-sb.sh
```

Before we jump to Windows lets try something as it has an interesting result

```bash
## Using bash
$ cd ~/work/wsl_sh
$ ./ls-sb.sh
Running ls in /bin/bash(2)
ls+sb.sh
ls-sb.sh
I am ./ls-sb.sh
$ ./ls+sb.sh
Running ls in /bin/bash(2)
ls+sb.sh
ls-sb.sh
I am ./ls+sb.sh

## I also played about with combinations of sh and path and -c
## getting different and surprising results.
bash -c <script>
sh -c <script>
bash -c ./<script>
bash ./<script>
bash <script>
etc...
```

**Surprise 1:** The shebang is not required (same in dash).

**Surprise 2:** The number of shells in `bash` is always 2, when you would sometimes expect just 1 and in `sh` it's not always as you would think either.

I think something in the shell(s) and/or OS looks ahead and optimises invocation. Open to suggestions on that...

Back to the tests...

Knowing the above you can replace `bash` with `sh` (or other) below and get a view as to what is happening.

We will first use `env` and `ps` to take a peek at the environment.  I've also printed the command `$0` so you can see how the shell is invoked.

*(This task gets huge, so I've reduced the size of the script below. I may take time to automate it and create a table of results.)*

There are:

- Four possible modes [][-i][-l][-i -l]
- Two possible shells [bash][sh]
- Two ways to run a script [-c ] [] 
  (-c can run executables without that it has to be a script)
- Four commands to try [env][ps][ls-sb.sh][ls+sb.sh]
- Lastly we can use with and without an explicit path [][./]

4 x 2 x 2 x 4 x 2 = 128 combinations!!

**That's a lot of combinations** and it would be all too easy to find more, so I will not list all of them here, but you can try some for yourself.

```
# For me, wsl screws up starting if I am not on C:\
C:

# Looking at env
wsl --shell-type standard --cd "~" -e bash -c 'echo ":$0:"; pwd; env'
wsl --shell-type standard --cd "~" -e bash -i -c 'echo ":$0:"; pwd; env'
wsl --shell-type standard --cd "~" -e bash -l -c 'echo ":$0:"; pwd; env'
wsl --shell-type standard --cd "~" -e bash -i -l -c 'echo ":$0:"; pwd; env'

# looking at ps
wsl --shell-type standard --cd "~" -e bash -c 'echo ":$0:"; pwd; ps au|grep $USER'
wsl --shell-type standard --cd "~" -e <shell> <switches> -c 'echo ":$0:"; pwd; ps au|grep $USER'
...
... etc


# Looking at the scripts run as commands
# Run as a command without shebang (explicit path)
wsl --cd "~/work/wsl_sh" -e <shell> <switches> -c 'echo ":$0:"; pwd;./ls-sb.sh"
# Run as command with shebang (explicit path)
wsl --cd "~/work/wsl_sh" -e <shell> <switches> -c 'echo ":$0:"; pwd;./ls+sb.sh"
...
... etc

# Again as command, but without explicit path (4 switch and 2 shell combinations)
...
... etc


# Looking at the scripts run as scripts and no explicit path (4 switch and 2 shell combinations)
wsl --cd "~/work/wsl_sh" -e <shell> <switches> 'ls+sb.sh'
wsl --cd "~/work/wsl_sh" -e <shell> <switches> 'ls-sb.sh'
...
... etc

# Again as scripts but with explicit path, etc.....
```

You will find that the ones that work are surprising and the ones that spawn less or more shells are not always obvious.

---

Note 1: The --cd "~" is necessary in a couple of the above cases, but not all as (and I've not looked into this), it seems wsl somehow changes the cwd despite the login scripts. **Feel free to add that as a variable too.**

Note 2: I included the unnecessary default `--shell-type standard` so to illustrate that the behaviour changes again if you were to use `login` or `none` instead. **MORE combinations arghhhh**

Note 3: `.`  (dot space) is an abbreviation of `source` in some shells.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sh script.sh` or you can do `./script.sh`, it makes difference and you choose which one works for you.