# WSL PATH environment variable is incorrect / zsh config not loaded

Tags: zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

When running `wsl` and interactively executing commands, the PATH is correctly initialized, since ~/.profile is sourced through ~/.zprofile by zsh.

However, while executing `wsl <my_command>`, the command is not found, since the PATH is not set correctly. The same happens for `wsl zsh -c <my_command>`.

Interactive:

```
PS C:\Users\Korpershoek_J> wsl
┌──(jjk㉿LT446W3J3)-[/mnt/c/Users/Korpershoek_J]
└─$ which redact
/home/jjk/bin/redact
```

Inline:

```
PS C:\Users\Korpershoek_J> wsl which redact
redact not found
```

### The PATH variable can be shown as follows

Interactive:

```
PS C:\Users\Korpershoek_J> wsl
┌──(jjk㉿LT446W3J3)-[/mnt/c/Users/Korpershoek_J]
└─$ echo $PATH
/home/jjk/.local/bin:/home/jjk/go/bin:/home/jjk/dotfiles/python_bin:/home/jjk/git/scripts/python_bin:/home/jjk/.cargo/bin:/home/jjk/nw_bin:/home/jjk/bin:/home/jjk/.config/kak/bin:/home/jjk/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/texlive/2022/bin/win32:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Users/Korpershoek_J/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox
```

Inline:

```
PS> wsl echo '$PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/texlive/2022/bin/win32:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Users/Korpershoek_J/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox
```

Or even:

```
PS> wsl zsh -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/texlive/2022/bin/win32:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Users/Korpershoek_J/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox
```

It is clear that the PATH variable is not correctly initialized. This is probably because ~/.zprofile is not sourced. How can I get /home/jjk/bin correctly in my path when executing WSL inline?

Comment: I believe this should have the answer you are looking for -- [What is the difference between calling a command via "wsl \[command\]" and opening a wsl shell and calling "\[command\]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66048183/what-is-the-difference-between-calling-a-command-via-wsl-command-and-opening).  If that doesn't answer it for you, let me know and we can dig deeper.  If it does answer it, make sure you click the option at the top of this question to close it out.  Thanks!