# Path environment variables not exposed from Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: linux, powershell, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run an executable that lives on a WSL that I've installed on my Windows machine from the Windows machine itself, i.e. from PowerShell. This program relies on some environment variables, in particular `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, to load the correct Linux libraries.

When I'm inside WSL, this works fine as I've assigned those environment variables, so for instance `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` returns a non-empty set of folders, starting with `/opt/nexant/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.5.281/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin`. `echo $PATH` also returns stuff. The executable runs fine when I invoke it from inside WSL.

However, from PowerShell, when I try to run `wsl /path/to/executable`, I get the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libifport.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Echoing `wsl echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from PowerShell gives an empty set.

I assume the cause of my issues is that these environment variables are not visible to the Windows OS. Is there some way that I can expose them? Even `wsl export PATH=....` does not seem to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between calling a command via "wsl \[command\]" and opening a wsl shell and calling "\[command\]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66048183/what-is-the-difference-between-calling-a-command-via-wsl-command-and-opening) -- If not, let me know, but the main thing is to tell the shell to run as an interactive (so that it will process `~/.bashrc` et. al.) and login (so that it will process `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile.d`, et. al.).

Comment: Great to hear!  If you get a chance, remember to upvote the question and answer there.  But regardless, good to hear it solved it for you.  Thanks for confirming!