# Starting WSL with SSH command from cmd

Tags: ssh, autohotkey, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, public-key

I am setting up hotkeys currently with AutoHotKey, inside I run the line `"Run "C:/Windows/System32/wsl.exe ssh host@ip"`

What this does it load that file and pass it that command as if you were to load it in CMD and run `"<program path> <command>"`

The issue starts here. If I have WSL open, my keychain is loaded and I can ssh to the IP, however running it from a CMD (or in this case AHK loading the file with the command) it throws a publickey denied error as "technically" its not ACTUALLY inside WSL yet.

I haven't found a workaround/anything that could make this work
I am expecting this to open up wsl and THEN run the ssh command, not try to do it all straight away because then the keychain isn't loaded

TL;DR
Trying to open wsl with via `"C:/Windows/System32/wsl.exe ssh USER@HOST"` being run in CMD/Batch File, this gives publickey denied as its not technically loaded up the keychain in WSL yet

Comment: Most likely you load the key through ~/.bashrc, so check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66048183/what-is-the-difference-between-calling-a-command-via-wsl-command-and-opening) and try `wsl -e bash -li -c 'ssh....'`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  @Chris.C mentioned it first, but [What is the difference between calling a command via "wsl \[command\]" and opening a wsl shell and calling "\[command\]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66048183/what-is-the-difference-between-calling-a-command-via-wsl-command-and-opening) will most likely resolve the issue.  If it does, you can click the option you'll see in the header that says something like, "This answered my question", and it will be marked closed.  Otherwise, let us know what happens, and we can dig in further.  Thanks!

Comment: Just as a side note, you do know that you can ssh from the Windows side just as well? There is no normal reason (that I can see) for you to launch wsl first and then ssh from wsl. But of course you might have some special setup that requires this.